# How to give link for users to Download the Csv Template in Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an requirement to give link to users in Apex Application to download the csv template.

I have created a link and created an process code as below for the users to download the csv file, But its showing some json error,

```
begin
-- Set the MIME type
owa_util.mime_header( 'application/octet', FALSE );
-- Set the name of the file
htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"');
-- Close the HTTP Header
owa_util.http_header_close;
-- Loop through all rows in EMP
for x in (select WORKSPACE,GROUPNAME,MEMBERS from CSV_NON_DYNAMIC_TEMPLATE where FILENAME='test.csv')
loop
 -- Print out a portion of a row,
 -- separated by commas and ended by a CR
 htp.prn(x.WORKSPACE ||','|| x.GROUPNAME ||','||x.MEMBERS|| chr(13));
end loop;
-- Send an error code so that the
-- rest of the HTML does not render
htmldb_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
end;
```

Even i code the process code to on load process, then its working the excel is creating but other than that no buttons or process code not working on the same page.

thanks

Comment: Perhaps your problem is with the forced error at the end which the comments indicate are to prevent the rest of the HTML from rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, saying you're getting "some json error" is not helpful. It helps to put the exact error message you're getting in your question.

Second, you probably have this process running at the Process step. Apex is submitting the page via Ajax, your process runs, returns an error to the page and you're getting your message.

1. Change your process to run at the Before Header point and change it so it has a server side condition of "Request = Value" and make the value "DOWNLOAD".
2. Change your button's action to Redirect to Page In This Application, and set the link to your page number with a request of "DOWNLOAD" (that's under the advanced section).

Comment: Hello, this is working fine but i want to get the data from database as dropdown list in excel template, how to work on it @eaolson

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking to do. You said you wanted csv, now you're saying you want a drop down in Excel?

Comment: yes i want dropdown in excel but the data should fetch from database.

Comment: There's no way to specify a dropdown in a CSV file. If you want an Excel-specific widget, you're going to need some sort of library that creates Excel binaries and I don't know of any that create form elements.